# cron every hour between 6 am to 18:00

Tags: cron

I don't have a box to test a cron job so I am posting it here.

I want to run a job every hour between 6 am to 18:00.This is what I have tried

```
0 6-18/1 * * * <command>
```

and

```
0 6-18 * * * <command>
```

Which one is the correct way of achieving it

Comment: You should choose the second

Comment: Both works. The first one syntax will be helpful, if you want to run say, every two hours between 6 AM - 6 PM

Comment: @BalajiSukumaran I am sure it wont run every two hours between 6 AM - 6 PM

Comment: 0 30 10-13 ? * MON,FRI           create a trigger that fires at 10:30, 11:30, 12:30, and 13:30, on every Monday and Friday

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Both should work, but I would probably use the second one.

Comment: Will use the first one although both are same...Why make things complicated :)